# What DML operations a table is performing inside Stored Procedure or SQL Functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-function, system-stored-procedures

I am using SQL Server 2014. I have some user defined tables like Customer, PurchaseOrder,  User, and so on. I am using those tables inside many stored procedures. In some cases, those stored procedures are almost 1000/1500 lines long.

Now I want to find out what operation(s) (*insert/update/delete*) those tables are doing inside every stored procedures.

I am doing it manually. But it is hell lot of effort. Besides, in manual effort, I might miss anything.

Can we write a SQL query by which without opening a stored procedure I can know what operation (*insert/update/delete*) a certain table is performing inside it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"Now I want to find out what operation(s) (insert/update/delete) those tables are doing inside every stored procedures."* Do you mean what DML operations are being performed against what tables in your Stored Procedures? Tables don't perform DML operations against Procedures; the tables are the ones affected by DML operations.

Comment: This, however, is far too broad at best. To *really* achieve this you'd need the definition of your procedures and a tool that can parse SQL and identify keywords and the processes the batch is doing. This is *far* from a trivial task. This is, truthfully, where good documentation comes into play.

Comment: DML operation like insert, update, delete. If we can find out for a single table, like Customer, what type of operations (insert/update/delete) getting performed on it inside Stored procedure, that is also fine for me.

Comment: Start by finding the dependencies - which is a common topic and has many discussions and solutions posted. Beyond that, there are no easy methods to determine what operations a stored procedure takes on a given table. Don't forget views and triggers can also "contribute" to the information you seek. This is a situation where good documentation, code writing consistency, and good naming conventions can help. Likely none of those were a focus of the development team unfortunately. Lessons to be learned.

Comment: Exactly what and how do you want to see information about your procedures? Explain your manual process. Are you unable to find what you need in the system catalogue views?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements you may find the following useful. You can search the complete text of all `procedures` / `functions` / `triggers` / `views` etc and look for matching key words.

```
select Schema_Name(o.schema_id)[schema], o.[name], o.type_desc
from sys.sql_modules m
join sys.objects o on o.object_id=m.object_id
where 
    m.definition like '%insert%customers%' or
    m.definition like '%update%customers%' or
    m.definition like '%delete%customers%' 
order by type_desc, name
```

This can help you narrow down and identify potential objects. This in itself is not precise since it may find a procedure where you update `orders` and then use `customers` in a `from` or `join` subsequently.

If you have conventions you can rely on such as a `delete` will always be `delete from customers` and not `delete customers` or `delete from c from...` then you can of course improve the matching to increase the relevance of what you find.

A tool such as Redgate's `SQLPrompt` is invaluable here as you can script out all your procedure names prefixed with `exec` , paste it into SSMS and immediately preview the entire procedure code of each in a pop-up window.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts of solving it